# image difference algorithm based on visual perception

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing

I have tried searching google for this for quite some time and have had no luck find what I need. What I am trying to do is I have a few different versions of the same image these versions being derived from the original by dithering them to a palette. The image is split into 8x8 tiles that use one of n palettes. I want to pick which palette looks best. There are a few questions on stackoverflow relating to image difference however they suggest a simple algorithm
Σ(R1<sub>n</sub>-R2<sub>n</sub>)^<sup>2</sup>+(G1<sub>n</sub>-G2<sub>n</sub>)^<sup>2</sup>+(B1<sub>n</sub>-B2<sub>n</sub>)^<sup>2</sup> and picking the lowest sum. Some suggest that to improve this a better delta algorithm can be used, I have tried CIEDE2000 still found the results unsatisfactory and in many instances I can manually pick a better tile. Note that I did do a bit of verification of my implementation of CIEDE2000 using precomputed data and used this library for http://www.getreuer.info/home/colorspace rgb to CIELab so I doubt that the reason I am a bit disappointed with the results is due to a bug and most of the time it does an okay job. What I want to do is implement a better algorithm than just the delta to pick the best tile. Does anyone know of a good algorithm for this (inclusive) or better terminology so that when I search for this I find more relevant information?

Comment: Sorry if I am being stupid today (it is possible), but what has choosing the best of N palettes got to do with differencing? Surely the selection of 1 palette from N is subjective, yet you are looking at algorithms based in statistics for some reason. What's the connection?

Comment: @MarkSetchell no you are not being stupid yes there is certainly objectiveness as for what image looks most similar however I am sure there is a way to find more accurately what tile looks best when a particular palette has been applied to it and dithered using an algorithm such as Floyd-Steinberg. An example of this lets say I have a dark tile and two palettes. One palette has many many bright colors, the other many dark colors. I dither the tile to both palettes and the one with the dark colors will look closer to the original and that is where the usage of image difference comes in.